# Laravel and GraphQL : How to use Passport of Laravel for Authentication when using laravel-graphql?

Tags: laravel, graphql

I want to use GraphQL in Laravel,I chose the package [laravel-graphql](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql) ,my question is:

How to use Passport of Laravel for Authentication when using laravel-graphql?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the package myself before, but from looking at the code I would say you can add a middleware in the configuration file `config/graphql.php` that performs the authentication and/or permission check:

```
/*
 * Any middleware for the 'graphql' route group
 */
'middleware' => ['auth:api'], // or 'auth' for normal authentication
```

If this doesn't work for you, there is also the possibility to override the controller used by the package. The configuration for this is also in the same configuration file. You could for example extend the existing controller to achieve what you want. Or you write an entirely new one.

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to install  laravel passport step by step after install  passport then you have to use

**@middleware(checks:["auth:api"])**
in schema.graphql file